# Clarify the definition of highest coefficient of a polynomial.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The highest coefficient of a polynomial is given to be 1.

Case  1) $ ax^2+bx+c $

Case  2) $ c(x-a)(x-b) $

I am specifically interested in the case 2 polynomial.

Edit: I am actually working on a problem with a polynomial of degree 10 in the form of $ c(x-a)(x-b)...(x-j) $ where the highest coefficient is given to be 1. If as one user said it is c, then how would it translate in the standard form, as in case 1? Will it be the coefficient of the highest power of x or the numerically greater of all coefficients?
Edit 2 : I got the correct solution by taking c as the highest coefficient.Maybe the question did mean leading coefficient.

Comment: Highest coefficient is $a$ in the first case and $c$ in the second

Comment: What exactly are you asking? the 'highest coefficient' could (in case 1) refer to either the coefficient of the highest power, a, or the 'largest coefficient' max{a,b,c}.

Comment: Do you mean [leading coefficient](http://www.mathwords.com/l/leading_coefficient.htm) of polynomial ?

Comment: Please see edit.